# Obtener el valor de una promesa

Tags: javascript, promesas, vue.js, es6, vuex

Estoy teniendo muchos problemas a la hora de obtener el valor de una *promise*. Básicamente quiero que el valor que devuelve una promesa quede asignado a una variable. Por ejemplo

> En este ejemplo se usan los siguientes elementos: [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js), [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex), `almacen` es un sinónimo de [`localForage`](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-getitem), un paquete para usar con el almacenamiento local.

Con este código obtengo el error `Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined`

```
let _accessToken = this.almacen.getItem('token')
```

Entonces uso una función `.then()` y obtengo el mismo error anterior

```
let _accessToken = this.almacen.getItem('token').then(carga => carga)
```

Entonces convierto mi variable `_accessToken` en una función.

```
let _accessToken = () => this.almacen.getItem('token').then((carga) => carga)
```

Aquí no tengo ningún error de sintaxis, pero la variable al ser evaluada me devuelve un error, que dice *`(error during evaluation)`*.

Ahora bien, si hago una función y uso la promesa dentro, si funciona. Por ejemplo:

```
function _getAccessToken () {
  this.almacen.getItem('token')               // consulto el almacenamiento
    .then((payload) => {                      // obtengo el resultado
      if (payload) {
        this.$store.state.token = payload     // lo guardo en una variable global
        this.$store.state.fuera = false       // altero otra variable
      } else this.$store.state.fuera = true
    }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
}
```

Aquí todo funciona como se espera, pero insisto en usar mi variable, así que la agrego:

```
let _accessToken = ''                            // declaro mi variable

function _getAccessToken () {
  this.almacen.getItem('token')
    .then((payload) => {
      if (payload) {
        _accessToken = payload                   // Aqui intento asignar la promesa
        this.$store.state.token = payload
        this.$store.state.fuera = false
      } else this.$store.state.fuera = true
    }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
}
```

Al evaluar la función, obtengo un error:
**`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`**.

<sup>La verdad solo estoy adivinando y no consigo atinarle.</sup>

#### ¿Cómo puedo guardar el valor de la promesa en la variable indicada?

### Edit

Para que puedan observar el funcionamiento de la aplicación he creado un pequeño jsfiddle que reproduce el problema:

https://jsfiddle.net/jstoledano/hjawnnh2/1/

Comment: Estás ejecutando _getAccessToken() e inmediatamente  a continuación leyendo el contenido de _accessToken?

Comment: Hola @SebastiánGrignoli, si entendí bien tu pregunta, estoy asignado el valor de la promesa, `payload`, cuando esta se resuelve... creo, no entiendo bien todavía esto de las promesas.

Comment: Te dice en qué línea arroja ese error?

Comment: Si arriba de `_accessToken = payload` ponés `console.log(_accessToken)` qué sale en la consola?

Comment: Estaría bueno si pudieras crear un fiddle con esa parte de tu código para que lo pueda probar...  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Mira @SebastiánGrignoli, ya hice un jsfiddle que reproduce el problema: https://jsfiddle.net/jstoledano/hjawnnh2/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, tenía ganas de aprender a usar Vue.js y no pensé que iba a empezar de atrás para adelante así que, ante todo, no sé lo que estoy haciendo respecto a observables, computed ni data properties. Pido disculpas de antemano si la solución es burda.

Lo que sí te puedo decir, es que para obtener el valor de la promesa **siempre debes retornar**. Así que donde dice:

```
function _getAccessToken () {
  localforage.getItem('token')
    .then((payload) => {
      if (payload) {
        this.$store.state.token = payload
        this.$store.state.fuera = false
      } else this.$store.state.fuera = true
    }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
}
```

No estás retornando nada. Esa función siempre asigna un valor undefined.

Si en cambio dijera:

```
function _getAccessToken () {
  return localforage.getItem('token')
    .then((payload) => {
      if (payload) {
        this.$store.state.token = payload
        this.$store.state.fuera = false
      } else {
        this.$store.state.fuera = true
      }
      return payload;
    }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
}
```

Después podrías decir:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  mixins: [sessionService],
  computed: Vuex.mapState(['token', 'fuera']),
  mounted () {
    this.getAccessToken().then((token)=>{
        this.accessToken=token;
    })
  }
})
```

Y se vería en tu template.

Te dejé un fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3o69qjpz/

Sin embargo, volviendo a tu fiddle original, tal parece que se puede optar por una solución más corta y tal vez sucia que es asignar directamente `this.accessToken` dentro del método `_getAccessToken` haciendo:

```
function _getAccessToken () {
  localforage.getItem('token')
    .then((payload) => {
      if (payload) {
        this.accessToken = payload     // <-- asignación directa
        this.$store.state.token = payload
        this.$store.state.fuera = false
      } else this.$store.state.fuera = true
    }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error ${e}`))
}
```

Y eso funciona igual. Pero insisto, esa no es la manera de trabajar con una promesa, porque la idea es que `_getAccessToken` sea *thenable* para cualquier otro uso y resuelva al valor del token. Este último workaround sólo toma ventaja de un efecto secundario y yo no lo usaría así.

Comment: Gracias, ya casi le entiendo a las _promises_.

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo problema con Axios. No podía ni enviar ni recibir ningún dato que manejara Axios y veía la información dentro de Axios pero no podía trabajarla afuera.

Me puse a leer sobre promesas y, concluí, que esta tecnología **siempre evalúa la operación para éxito o fracaso primero**. **Si existe error nunca pasa por la función** del `.then` y si hay éxito lo hace.

Siempre me daba el mismo error

> Cannot read property 'xxxx' of undefined

y era porque nunca se configuraba la asignación o cuando se hacía la asignación todavía no había entrado el dato (asincronismo). Al retornar la respuesta a otro `.then` se asegura uno de tomar el dato.

```
axios().then(response => {return response}.then{respuesta => { this.dato = respuesta}.catch{...}
```

Comment: No sale sobrando que expliques un poco más el código. Saludos.